# Rails validate uniqueness of attribute according to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, validates-uniqueness-of

I have a model `User`, which `has_many` `Profile`. I also have `Report` model, which `belongs_to` `Profile`.

How can I make sure that one user has only one report? Something like

```
class Report
  validate_uniqueness_of profile_id, scope: :user 
end
```

would be great, but of course it doesn't work. (I don't want to attach user field to Report, because it mixes up ownership chain).

Comment: You have to use custom validation. Rails does not allow validating uniqueness outside the model scope

Comment: Hi techvineet: could you suggest how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an idea on how to implement custom validations. Check this

```
class Report
    validate :unique_user

    def unique_user
        if self.exists?("profile_id = #{self.profile_id}")
          errors.add(:profile_id, "Duplicate user report")
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, then all the profiles of a user will have the same report, right?
If that's so, it means that a profile belongs to a user, so why don't you model it like that? Eg:

```
class User 
  has_many :profiles
  has_one :report
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :report, through: :user
end

class Report
  belongs_to :user
end
```